# Download SQL database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I have a server on Microsoft Server Management Studio that I need to download in order to work on it locally.

When I right click on the database and go to `Tasks -- Export Data` I get the `SQL Server Import Export Wizard`. I am able to pick a source, but I can't find the write destination to allow me to download the file locally.

I don't want to transfer the files to another server, I just want to have to local file to work with.

Is this the right approach? Or is there a better way to handle this task?

Comment: You want to do a [Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I tried that, but how can I read the `.bak` file?

Comment: That's the Restore part. You don't "read" the file, you restore it onto your local instance.

Comment: If you want to work locally, you **need** a local server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to transfer the files to another server....

A SQL Server database is a complex binary structure. To read it / work with it, you need a copy of SQL Server on the machine you want to work with it on. The Developer edition would be a good option for downloading to a local machine, or you could install the free version and export data to a local database.

If what you are trying to do is to just see the data without any of the SQL Server functionality, then you can export them to different types of files through the import/export functionality. However, unless the amount of data involved is quite small, I would really recommend against this. The organization and cross-referencing of data can be quite extensive depending on how the database was designed.

These are about your only two options. What you end up doing may depend on what you are planning to do with the data.